# How to submit the custom form data in database in WordPress without plugin using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have a created a contact form in the `function.php` and added short code on my page and it's working. I am getting my form.

```
function st_contact_form(){
ob_start();
    ?>
      <div class="contact_form-wrapper popup-contact-form">
         <form action="" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="Phone no" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="form-group select-service">
            <select class="form-control" name="type_of_services" required>
                <option selected disabled>Select Service</option>
                <option value="1">Testing one</option>
                <option value="2">Testing two</option>

            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLR0">
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="2" required></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" class="btn_st btn_maroon form_submit_btn">
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'st_contact_form' );
```

I added below script in script file and validation is working. Now I want to know how to submit the form in wordpress? Should I create a table? or I have to create process.php file and add some logic?

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        required:true,
        email: true,
        emailExt: true
    },
    mobileno: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    },
    type_of_services: {
        required:true
    },
    message: {
        required:true
    }
},
submitHandler: function(r) {
     if(isReqInprogress){
        return;
       }
    isReqInprogress = true;
    $.ajax({
                url:base_url+"/wp-content/themes/mytheme/process.php",

        type: "post",
        data:{name:name,email:email,mobileno:mobileno,type_of_services:type_of_services,message:message},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(response) {
           alert("success");


    isReqInprogress = false;
        }


    })
}
});
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$data = $_POST;
$to = $data['email'];
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//$mail = wp_mail($data['email'], $subject, $body, $headers );
//if ($mail) {
    $wpdb->insert('wp_contact',
        array(
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mobileno' => $data['mobileno'],
            'message' => $data['message'],
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
        )
    );
//}

?>
```

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my solution,

I added below code in `function.php` and using shortcode I am getting my form on webpage

```
function st_contact_form(){
ob_start();
    ?>
      <div class="contact_form-wrapper popup-contact-form">
         <form action="" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
             <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="mobileno" placeholder="Phone no" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="form-group select-service">
            <select class="form-control" name="type_of_services" required>
                <option selected disabled>Select Service</option>
                <option value="1">Testing one</option>
                <option value="2">Testing two</option>

            </select>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 paddingLR0">
         <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" rows="2" required></textarea>
         </div>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group ">
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" class="btn_st btn_maroon form_submit_btn">
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'st_contact_form' );
```

Now next step is, JQuery validation and Ajax. Also I created a `process.php` file in my theme

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required:true
    },
    email: {
        required:true,
        email: true
    },
    mobileno: {
        required:true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: true
    },
    type_of_services: {
        required:true
    },
    message: {
        required:true
    }
},

submitHandler: function(form) {
    if(isReqInprogress){
        return;
       }
        $.ajax({
        url:"/wp-content/themes/stratevic/process.php",
        type: "post",
        data:$('#contact_form').serialize(),           
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(response) {

        alert("Your message has been received and we will be contacting you shortly to follow-up.");
            isReqInprogress = false;
             }
    });
}
});
```

**Process.php**

Note: I have created a contact table in my database

```
<?php
define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);

global $wpdb;        // <--- making $wpdb as global
$data = $_POST;
$query=$wpdb->insert('contact',
        array(
             'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['mobileno'],
            'type_of_services' => $data['type_of_services'],
            'message' => $data['message']
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
        )
);


 if ($query) {
    $response['error'] = "true";

    }else{
    $response['error'] = "false";
    } 
echo json_encode($response);
exit();
    // $wpdb->show_errors(); 

?>
```

that's it. It's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide your process.php file so I'm just gonna assume that is where the mail logic happens. As you initially suspected you could create a database table and use the [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class to insert the data into that table.

```php
 // .../process.php

 ...
// pls escape the POST with a escape method of your choice
$data = $_POST;
$to = $data['email'];
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$mail = wp_mail($data['email'], $subject, $body, $headers );
if ($mail) {
    $wpdb->insert('wp_email_subscription',
        array(
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mobileno' => $data['mobileno'],
            'message' => $data['message'],
        ...
        ),
        array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
        ...
        )
    );
}
```

Keep in mind that you also have to create the fields in your table according to your needs.

Update: Regarding your comment that the `process.php` file being a placeholder now, you would place it within your themes root directory. An example being

```
wordpress/wp-content/themes/*your-theme*
```

where you have to replace *your-theme* with the theme you selected in the wordpress backend.

Now I imagine the e-mail is not send out yet this would probably be to broad of an answer but you could look into already answered questions on how to set up a wp mail etc. or read the codex [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). For the mailing to work you also need to update your wordpress mail settings and have a Server with the possibility to send out emails.

The Wordpress wp_mail() function also returns a boolean value with this you could also fill your database depending on the state of the mail being send.

I also updated the code example above accordingly.

Comment: Actually I haven;t created yet process.php. This file name is just a example. I need to know after clicking on submit button it will call the process.php but where should I create this file? and what code I have to use it?

Comment: I am new in wordpress and trying to submit the form. I created a table in the database

Comment: I want to know where should I go and add this code?

Comment: I updated the question. With that you should have a Idea on how to continue.

Comment: What I understood, I created a file called a process.php in my theme and added your answer. I just change the table name from wp_email_subscription to wp_contactus.

Comment: Now I need to know in the script. How it will call process.php from the script?

Comment: you are already calling the script via the $.ajax({url:base_url+"/process.php"... method. If you were to var_dump(); or debugg within your process php file you would know if it was called accordingly. If your unsure as to how to work with wordpress and the ajax context you could try  following guides like this: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/

Comment: base_url+"/process.php is http://text.com/process.php. Should I write full path?

Comment: I updated my code with process.php. mail function is commented as of now.